# How i can optimize my ranking query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Multiple records are being saved for each date against each subscription id. There is coins column, All subscriber gets few coins. It is basically a rewarding system. I want to get the rank of current subscriber. There are 2 tables that are being used.

1. user_rewards (which saves all the records with coins)
2. coins_history (if coins are used, then i add the used coins in coins history table)

For example if user has earned total of 1000 coins, it remains 1000 in user reward table, and if he has used 200 coins somewhere, i add an entry in coins history table. So currently he has 800 coins left. I will have to find rank with current coins.

For example, I have 5 records exist in my user reward against 3 subscriber ids. I want to get the rank of one subscriber against his subscription_id.

```
+-----------------+--------------+-------+
| subscription_id | date_awarded | coins |
+-----------------+--------------+-------+
| 525252 | 2020-09-11 | 10 |
| 454545 | 2020-09-11 | 20 |
| 989898 | 2020-09-11 | 10 |
| 525252 | 2020-09-10 | 50 |
| 454545 | 2020-09-10 | 30 |
+-----------------+--------------+-------+
```

The subscription ids `525252` has `60` coins, 989898 has `10` coins and `454545` has `50` coins. But subscription id `525252` has used `40` of his coins, `40` coins are added in coins history table. So `454545` ranks first with `50` coins, `525252` ranks 2nd with `20` coins and `989898` ranks 3rd with `10` coins.

So for getting rank of user. I get sum of coins from user reward table, then minus it with coins history table against that subscription id. Then find the rank against his current unused coins. Below is my query, Query took 34.0794 sec.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS aboveRank 
FROM 
(
   SELECT subscription_id  
   FROM user_rewards 
   GROUP BY subscription_id 
   HAVING SUM(coins) > 
    (Select (SELECT IFNULL(sum(coins), 0)  
             FROM user_rewards 
             WHERE subscription_id = 525252) - 
            (SELECT IFNULL(sum(coins), 0) as coins 
             FROM `coins_history` 
             where subscription_id = 525252) as z
    ) 
) t
```

Note: I have around 800000 records in one month, it will keep on increasing daily, So need to optimize my current query, I am using MySQL and PHP.

Comment: This is a case where you may want to consider denormalisation and store the balance of the calculation within the user table (or in another table for locking reasons) and update this value through triggers (if you need real-time updates to ranking) or through a regularly-run batch job (if you are happy if a transaction's impact on ranking appears later). Calculate the ranking based on the stored balances. If you use the batch job approach, then you can even generate the ranking based on the balances in the batch job, saving you further time.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the total coins per subscriber using `union all` and `group by`.  Then use window functions for the ranking:

```
select c.*
from (select subscription_id, sum(coins) as coins,
             rank() over (order by coins desc) as seqnum
      from ((select subscription_id, - sum(coins) as coins
             from user_rewards ur
             group by subscription_id
            ) union all
            (select subscription_id, sum(coins)
             from coins_history ch
             group by subscription_id
            ) 
           ) c
       group by subscription_id
      ) c
where subscription_id = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am getting this error, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by coins "desc") as seqnum from ((select subscription_id, - sum(c' at line 3

Comment: @FaisalKhan . . . This version requires MySQL 8+.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you provide the same query for older version of mysql.

Comment: On MySQL 8.0 it returns, unknown column  'ur' in 'field list' and what will be the solution for MySQL 5+

Comment: For example, The subscription id has 1000 coins in user rewards and 300 used coins in coins history, so it should return 700 and rank according to my 700 current coins. But the query is returning "-700" and my ranks is very low because of minus sign with it.

Comment: @FaisalKhan . . . Just switch the minus signs.  It is hard to tell from your question which value is being subtracted from which other one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... By switching the minus sign, it didn't return me the true rank. Basically i am subtracting the coins of "coins_history" table from "user_rewards" table.

Comment: @FaisalKhan . . . I switched it back.  This is doing exactly that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... In that way, negative value is returning.

Comment: @FaisalKhan . . . Then you have data where the sum of the coins in user rewards is less than the sum in coins history.